# chroot: failed with No such file or directory yet file exists

Tags: debian, chroot

```bash
# chroot /mnt/sys1 /bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory
```

But it is NOT the usual `chroot: failed with No such file or directory` problem because the  file is right there:

```bash
/mnt/sys1# dir -l bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1234376 2022-03-27 14:40 bin/bash*

/mnt/sys1# dir -l 
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 2021-05-08 14:27 bin -> usr/bin/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 2021-05-08 14:27 lib -> usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 2021-05-08 14:27 lib32 -> usr/lib32/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 2021-05-08 14:27 lib64 -> usr/lib64/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    10 2021-05-08 14:27 libx32 -> usr/libx32/

/mnt/sys1# dir -ld usr/lib*
drwxr-xr-x 78 root root 4096 2023-04-08 23:48 usr/lib/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2023-04-08 18:35 usr/lib32/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2023-04-08 18:35 usr/lib64/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 2023-04-08 18:37 usr/libexec/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2023-04-08 18:35 usr/libx32/

/mnt/sys1# dir -l usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1234376 2022-03-27 14:40 usr/bin/bash*

/mnt/sys1# file /bin/bash bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=31c321f9f0c1f86a379f7efaaeb75f707998f27f, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
bin/bash:  ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=31c321f9f0c1f86a379f7efaaeb75f707998f27f, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

/mnt/sys1# cmp /bin/bash bin/bash && echo same
same
```

And unlike the possible missing dependencies, it fails before `ldd` kicks in:

```bash
# strace -o /tmp/strace.log chroot /mnt/sys1 /bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory

# cat /tmp/strace.log
. . .
lstat("/mnt", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/mnt/sys1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
chroot("/mnt/sys1")                  = 0
chdir("/")                              = 0
execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash"], 0x7ffee9b47ff8 /* 121 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "chroot: ", 8)                 = 8
write(2, "failed to run command '/bin/bash"..., 33) = 33
write(2, ": No such file or directory", 27) = 27
. . .
```

IE `execve` complains that `/bin/bash` not exist ***but*** it is *right* there!

Any idea?

```bash
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Comment: Please add `file /bin/bash /mnt/sys1/bin/bash`. I'm thinking it's a different architecture

Comment: Added @roaima. They are exactly the same. The problem happened *after* I `rsync` all my `/usr` files into it, with `rsync -vaRC --exclude='**5.10.0-21**' /usr /mnt/sys1`

Comment: I rsync all my /usr files into it because I was trying to fix https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741328/failed-to-load-usr-share-icons-adwaita-24x24-status-image-missing-png, which exhibits in /mnt/sys1 but not in my newly created debian stable. I only copied /usr because I thought it should be enough, and I excluded '**5.10.0-21**' because the two debian stable has different kernel versions, and I don't have enough disk space for both. I've copied the whole /usr over now, but the problem persists. I now think the copying /usr only might be the root reason, but I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Yes @roaima, the Conclusion: _The chroot needs to contain at least a minimal installation of a system, including device files and libraries that are needed to run the executables within it_ pretty much summarizes my situation here. Give up fixing it and closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can only run `chroot` as the root user.

Unfortunately (at least Debian's) `man chroot` omits to mention this but it is stated in the [official online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/chroot),

> `chroot` runs a command with a specified root directory. On many systems, only the super-user can do this.

Comment: Yes, I am running chroot as the root user.

Comment: You've included a non-root prompt for your commands in the question. Either remove the prompt or make it obviously a root prompt please

Comment: Done. Those commands now looks like comments.